# Model querys Django

Tags: python, django

i have this model with the following relation.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserModel(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)


class BlogModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        UserModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ", " + str(self.title)
```

How do i query every blogpost a paticular user had made? Thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look "through" a relation with double underscores (`__`), so you can query with:

```
BlogModel.objects.filter(user__user=user_object)
```

so if you want to display the `BlogModel`s for the logged in user, you replace *`user_object`* with `request.user`.